# Adding full page figures in Latex, how?

Tags: latex, figure

I have a full-page figure that LaTeX keeps putting at the end because of its size.

I would like it to be integrated on a separate page in the flow of text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
```

- h = here
- b = botom
- t = top
- p = page of floats

Algorithm will try the current position in document first, then bottom, then top and then on a seperate page. If you just specify `'h'` you will force placement where the figure command is in the document. The order is encoded by you -- i.e., you could specify `ptbh` which would force a reverse order of evaluation.

p.s., I would strongly recomend anyone using latex to use [lyx](http://www.lyx.org/). Its just as powerfull as straight latex but its wysiwyg and you can drop to tex anywhere you want.

Comment: ok, I used here, but I changed to "p" and it makes the figure goes to another page, just as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you also want the caption to be rotated, you can also use

```
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
```

That also eliminates the need for using `angle=90` or something like that

Answer (score 10):

```
\begin{figure*}[tb] 
\centering
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth]{./fig/fig5.eps}}
\caption{The SAP data model based on an UML class diagram: classes and relationships.}
\label{fig:Fig5}
\end{figure*}
```